# Determine the top 'm' most occurring k-Page-sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

A website has several web-pages and there are a lot of users who are accessing the web-site.
Assume--

```
user 1 has access pattern : x->y->z->a->b->c->d->e->f    
user 2 has access pattern : z->a->b->c->d
user 3 has access pattern : y->z->a->b->c->d
user 4 has access pattern : a->b->c->d
```

and list goes on for lot many users which are finite and numbered.
Now the question is we have to determine the top m most occurring k-Page-sequence.
For the above example result will be : (k=3,m=3) a->b->c , b->c->d , z->a->b.

I could not really reach a concrete solution here. Whatever data structures I use, I have to go through all the nodes and lists. May be I can create a hash table where key is something like "abc" and the value is the number of times it occurred. But then finding 'm' most occurring in the hash table would always be a pain.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but way k=3 and m=3 ? i see a->b->c 4times

Comment: m=3, k=3 => 3 most occurring  3-page sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem just as you have described, using the `k`-tuples as the keys for your hash table.

Then for extracting the top `m` elements can be performed by iterating through each hash key, and performing a bubble sort on the current top `m` elements, and your current element.  This will have a time complexity of `O(m*N)`, where `N` is the number of keys in your hash table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let `p[i]` be a pattern of user `i`.  For every pattern `i`:
2. For every substring `s` of length `k` in `p[i]`:
3. if (`s` in `hashmap`) `hashmap[s]++` else put `s` into `hashmap`.
4. Let `k` be a number of keys in the `hashmap`. Sort keys in descending order by their values. Return `m` first keys after sorting.

`O(klogk)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

1. If hashing is feasible:

   - put them all into a hash map(which maps a sequence to a number of its occurrences).
   - How to find the top `m` elements in the hash map? There are several ways:

     1. Put them all into an array and sort it. The time complexity is `O(n log n)`, where `n` is the number of entries in the map.
     2. Iterate over the hash map entries and maintain a priority queue with top `m` elements seen so far. The time complexity is `O(n log m)`.
     3. Put them all into an array and choose the `m`-th element using the quickselect algorithm. Pick all that are not greater than it. The time  complexity is `O(n)` or `O(n + m * log m)` if we need to get top `m` entries in a sorted order.
2. If hashing is not feasible, you can use a suffix data structure(array, tree, automaton) to count the number of occurrences of each sequence and then choose the best `m` the same way as in 1.

Comment: Would using a suffix data structure improve the space and/or time complexities?

Comment: @ankitG If we assume that a hash map is perfect(insert/find always in `O(1)`), then no.